# How to call backend method from ZK page?

Tags: java, zk

I want to dynamically generate image with onClick method to call from page. But no matter how I tried, it goes failed.

My code in the backend class is like:

```
public class RuleController  extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
     .......
   Image imageTemp = (Image)image.clone();
   ZScript script = new ZScript("java","delCondition1("+indexCon1+")");
   EventHandler evthdl = new EventHandler(script);
   imageTemp.addEventHandler("onClick", evthdl);
   ........

   public void delCondition1(int index){
      .........
   }
}
```

but after I Clicked the image on page, errors came out:

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``delCondition1(0);'' : Command not found: delCondition1( int ) : at Line: 1 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``delCondition1(0);'' : delCondition1 ( 0 ) 

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.zkoss.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:76)
at org.zkoss.lang.Exceptions.wrap(Exceptions.java:163)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException$Aide.wrap(UiException.java:51)
at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:136)
at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInterpreter.java:342)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:970)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3135)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3089)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1846)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1618)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1321)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:611)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:487)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:495)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:479)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:479)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems the onClick triggered java code can't find the method : delCondition1(int),  Why?  How can I set the method to call?

Comment: If I write the code in the zul page, between  <zscript><![CDATA[   ]]</zscript>, code can run.

Comment: You don't need that `zscript`. This is suitable for prototyping but not recommended for production. Simply use `@Listen("onClick = #yourImageId")` annotation on your method. Also why don't you go with MVVM ?

Comment: My ImageId is generated dynamically, so I can't use @Listen("onClick = #yourImageId"), do you have any method else?

Comment: Ah OK, so use an [EventListener](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Listening), I have posted example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `zscript` in production, this is suitable for prototyping only. See [the statement](https://books.zkoss.org/zkessentials-book/master/controlling_components/in_zscript.html) from the ZK team.

If your image is defined in your ZUL file, simply use `@Listen("onClick = #yourImageId")` annotation on your method.

If your image is generated dynamically, use an [EventListener](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Listening) to add the `onClick` event to your image :

```
public class RuleController  extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    ...

    Image imageTemp = (Image)image.clone();

    EventListener<Event> actionListener = new SerializableEventListener<Event>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            delCondition1(indexCon1);
        }
    };

    imageTemp.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, actionListener);

    ...

    public void delCondition1(int index){
        ...
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://books.zkoss.org/zkessentials-book/master/controlling_components/in_controller.html).

Comment: Yes, it works in addEventListener,  I don't know why the addEventHandler is not work.